# Is this a good way to grind beans for espresso?

Tags: espresso

I use a Hamilton Beach grinder.  It's a rotating blade type.  I want the best possible grind.  Here's how I do it: after placing 1 tbs of beans in the grinder I begin grinding to a count of 5 (approximately five seconds), then I turn the grinder upside down, I then grind for 4 counts, again I turn the grinder upside down, and then grind for 3 counts.

Does that sound about right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find any questions like this from yesterday. Are you certain that you posted it here? The way our site works, you need to ask one question at a time, so that we may address each question separately. Right now you have two completely different questions, so you need to separate this into two posts.

Comment: It seems that you posted a question as an answer, which isn't how this site works. It takes a bit of learning at first so you're on the right track!

Comment: Indeed, now that you've posted this as a question, you can get answers, so all is well. I've edited your question to focus just on the question you actually meant to ask. I also dropped your second question - as Catija mentioned, we want one per question.

Comment: @Jefromi, hm.... Looks like a migration candidate for Coffee SE to me?

Comment: My guess is that exact timing is too preference- and equipment-specific for us to be able to answer definitively; whatever works for you is right.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to actually make espresso in an espresso machine, a blade grinder won't do it, regardless of your method. It's simply too inconsistent. You'll get some small bits, some big bits and some dust.

Espresso needs to be ground fine - more fine than drip or French press or cold brew. You need a purpose-built grinder for this. You might get away with a high-quality burr grinder but for really great quality espresso, you need a specialty grinder.

Now, if you're just using espresso beans in your normal coffee maker, that's not espresso but your grind doesn't need to be as fine.

Info about grind taken from [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ineedcoffee.com/coffee-grind-chart/amp) and there's a lot more in-depth there, too.